# Equal distribution of row depending on its condition

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

I am new to SQL and i am not familiar with Stored Procedure, i am currently using SQL 2014. I have 3 table;

```
> tblTransaction
    ID  Owner     Country   Region    Vendor    Description
    1   NULL      Country1  Region1   Vendor2   
    4   NULL      Country1  Region1   NULL  
    7   NULL      Country1  Region1   Vendor2   
    10  NULL      Country1  Region1   NULL  
    13  NULL      Country1  Region2   Vendor3   
    16  NULL      Country1  Region2   Vendor3   Description1
    19  NULL      Country1  Region2   Vendor3   Description1
    2   NULL      Country2  Region1   Vendor1   Description1
    5   NULL      Country2  Region2   Vendor1   
    8   NULL      Country2  Region1   Vendor1   
    11  NULL      Country2  Region1   Vendor2   Description1
    14  NULL      Country2  Region1   NULL  
    17  NULL      Country2  Region1   Vendor2   
    20  NULL      Country3  Region1   NULL  
    3   NULL      Country3  Region2   Vendor3   
    6   NULL      Country3  Region2   Vendor3   Description1
    9   NULL      Country3  Region2   NULL  
    12  NULL      Country3  Region2   NULL  
    15  NULL      Country3  Region1   Vendor1   
    18  NULL      Country3  Region2   Vendor1

> tblSkillMatrix
 Owner   IsTeamLead  Country    Vendor   Region     Description
Person1      N      Country1    Vendor1  Region1    
Person2      Y      Country2    Vendor2  Region2    Description1
Person3      N      Country2    Vendor3  Region2    
Person4      Y      Country1    Vendor4  Region1    Description1
Person5      N      Country1    Vendor4  Region1    

> tblAssignment(Output)
ID  Owner     Country   Region    Vendor    Description
1   Person1   Country1  Region1   Vendor2   
4   Person1   Country1  Region1   NULL  
7   Person5   Country1  Region1   Vendor2   
10  Person5   Country1  Region1   NULL  
13  Person4   Country1  Region2   Vendor3   
16  Person2   Country1  Region2   Vendor3   Description1
19  Person2   Country1  Region2   Vendor3   Description1
2   Person2   Country2  Region1   Vendor1   Description1
5   Person2   Country2  Region2   Vendor1   
8   Person2   Country2  Region1   Vendor1   
11  Person4   Country2  Region1   Vendor2   Description1
14  Person3   Country2  Region1   NULL  
17  Person3   Country2  Region1   Vendor2   
20  Person4   Country3  Region1   NULL  
3   Person3   Country3  Region2   Vendor3   
6   Person4   Country3  Region2   Vendor3   Description1
9   Person4   Country3  Region2   NULL  
12  Person2   Country3  Region2   NULL  
15  Person1   Country3  Region1   Vendor1   
18  Person3   Country3  Region2   Vendor1
```

Need to update tblTransaction based on the condition in tblSkillMatrix and once done, insert it to table tblAssignment.

Below are the requirements:

- Assign ID to TeamLead(if IsTeamLead = 'Y'). Description =
  'Description1'
- If Country does not exist in tblSkillMatrix and if    Vendor is NULL,
  assign IDs equally to TeamLeads only regardless of    its Country.
- Assign max of 2 transaction to TeamLead per Country.
- Non-TeamLead must be equally assinged per Country.  For
  Non-TeamLead, if Country does not exist in tblSkillMatrix, use Region
  instead. Needs to be equally distributed.

Comment: sql server <> mysql, please don't tag products not involved!

Comment: what are the conditions? It would be helpful to see the output you expect in table 3 after the script is run

Comment: So you want to match all 4 conditions (except Owner) from Table 2 to Table 1 and then return the matching Table1.ID and Table2.Owner? Are you expecting to replace the NULL Vendor values as well? What happens when there is no match?

Comment: the conditions are in table2. Need to replace 'NULL' on Owner column in table1.

Comment: what is the expected result ?

Comment: hi @Squirrel , I have updated my question. Please check.

Comment: the expected result is tblAssignment @Squirrel